# What is protocol attribute in the module of ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

In the `ejabberd.erl` module, the `-protocol` attribute is used:

```
-module(ejabberd).
-author('alexey@process-one.net').


-protocol({xep, 4, '2.9'}).
-protocol({xep, 86, '1.0'}).
```

What's the usage of this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are user-defined Erlang module attributes which can be used both for information and programmatically.

For example in `mod_ping.erl` module which implemented [XEP-0199](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html) (XMPP Ping) you can see its attibute:

```
-module(mod_ping).
-protocol({xep, 199, '2.0'}).
```

And also in `mod_vcard.erl` which implemented bot [XEP-0054](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html) (vcard-temp) and [XEP-0055](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html) (Jabber Search) you can see their attributes:

```
-module(mod_vcard).
-protocol({xep, 54, '1.2'}).
-protocol({xep, 55, '1.3'}).
```

In [this page](http://xmpp.org/extensions/) you can find a full list of XMPP Extensions.

---

Also it is good to know that using `ModuleName:module_info(attributes)` you can get a list of module attributes.